# Leaflet r map saving issue

Tags: r, leaflet

[image]
I have used addlogo to my leaflet map which displays my organizations' logo on the bottom right of the map. 
This is logo visible in the viewer within R. However when I save the map the logo is not visible in either a png or HTML format. Please view the code below and the attachments.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Best Wishes
MD

I have used webshot to save as HTML but still the same issue

## save the file to png

```
mapshot(m, file = "myfilepath", remove_controls = NULL)
```

The output should be saved with the logo at the bottom right hand visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using webshot, you should consider to try [webshot2](https://github.com/rstudio/webshot2). See [my detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61479575/1953250) to the similar case.

The code:

```
# Webshot and phantomjs have been previously installed.
library(webshot2)
```

Comment: I have prepared a blog post including various details about webshot2. You can see the details from http://www.ozturkibrahim.com/export-save-r-graphs-with-webshot/